# How to access Azure API Managment deployed in Vnet without using application Gateway? (For clients that exist outside the Vnet)

Tags: azure-api-management, vnet

I have an API management instance that is integrated with a Vnet - the ability to access the API management instance is possible to internal consumers.

I would like certain public clients to also access this API management instance - the way described in the Azure documentation is to make use of Application Gateway:

[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-integrate-internal-vnet-appgateway]

see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-integrate-internal-vnet-appgateway

Is anyone aware of an alternate approach not implementing Application Gateway?

Answer (score 0):

Use Function App with Vnet Integration:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-vnet

The function app exposes public endpoint and has ability to make internal call to Vnet.

Comment: Whether or not to use this approach really depends on your application/solution required. Consider carefully before taking this approach as application gateway may be a more feasible approach.