# Identify requestor which call Internal Azure APIM through External Azure Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I do have external Azure Gateway which allows calling internal API services through internal (not public) APIM.

For billing purpose, I need to know who exactly (IP or some type of IDs) make a call.

I thought that could get this information from APIM logs.

I've tried to send custom header, with some sort of IDs, during API call -  but I could not find any meaningful information in APIM diagnostic logs.

Could you please share your thoughts and suggestions, how to achieve the above goal?

Comment: You can try these references:
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68244178/how-to-connect-to-internal-api-management-through-an-app-gateway-externally. 
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59404413/azure-api-management-call-non-azure-api. 
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59066311/how-to-access-azure-api-managment-deployed-in-vnet-without-using-application-gat. 
4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52371979/querying-azure-apim-diagnostic-logs

Comment: actually API , APIM and Gateway work fine .  External Requestor able to call backend api ( external requestor -> external gateway -> internal APIM -> internal API .) 

I need identify e.g. if i have 2 or more requestors, who exactly called my API.

Answer (score 0):

You can know the requestor by pulling [reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/current-ga/reports/list-by-user) of that particular API management using rest API. Here you get option to filter the reports by User and User-Ids

reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/current-ga/reports/list-by-user